# Remove floor shadows in solid works render by macro

Tags: vba, macros, rendering, solidworks

I'm trying develop a macro that runs renders and saves them automatically. The files (with path) are listed, and extracted from an Excel file, then opened and rendered.
This part works fine, but now I would like to remove the floor shades (and floor reflections) within the VBA code. I tried to record a macro while turning off the floor shades in a random SolidWorks file, but SolidWorks unfortunately doesn't record this part.
Does any one have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

```
' 

******************************************************************************
' C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\swx11684\Macro1.swb - macro recorded on 11/25/16 by Omar
' ******************************************************************************

Sub main()
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long
Dim status As Boolean
Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Dim i As String
Dim j As String
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swRayTraceRenderer As SldWorks.RayTraceRenderer
Dim swRayTraceRenderOptions As SldWorks.RayTraceRendererOptions
Dim errors As Long
Dim warnings As Long
Dim filePath As String
Dim Scene As SldWorks.SWScene
Dim swConfig As SldWorks.Configuration
Dim swPoint As SldWorks.MathPoint
Dim point As Variant
Dim swVector As SldWorks.MathVector
Dim vect As Variant


'Dim xlApp As Object, xlWB As Object
'Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'i = file name
'j = file extention

'i = "bp01p0006" example
'j = "simbeton - Solidworks\bp - betonplaten\bp01 - simvlak\" example

'Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(“C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\Renders Rob\Lijst.xlsx”)


y = 0


n = 0

Do While n < 5
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\Renders Rob\Lijst.xlsx")
    If xlWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").offset(y, 0) = "" Then
        y = y + 1
        n = n + 1
        Else
            j = xlWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").offset(y, 0).value
            i = xlWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").offset(y, 1).value
            z = xlWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").offset(y, 2).value
            xlWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").offset(y, 0) = ""
            y = y + 1
    End If

Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

filePath = "" & j & "\" & i & ".SLDPRT"
Set swModel = swApp.OpenDoc6(filePath, swDocPART, swOpenDocOptions_Silent, "", errors, warnings)

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc

Set swApp = _
Application.SldWorks

Dim myModelView As Object
Set myModelView = Part.ActiveView
myModelView.AddPerspective
Part.ViewZoomtofit2
Part.ViewZoomtofit2
Part.ViewZoomtofit2
Part.ViewZoomtofit2
Part.ViewZoomtofit2
Part.ShowNamedView2 "*Isometric", 7
Part.ViewZoomtofit2

Part.ViewDisplayShaded
Dim activeModelView As Object
Set activeModelView = Part.ActiveView
activeModelView.DisplayMode = swViewDisplayMode_e.swViewDisplayMode_ShadedWithEdges
Part.ClearSelection2 True
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SketchBoxSelect("0.000000", "0.000000", "0.000000", "0.000000", "0.000000", "0.000000")
Part.ViewDisplayShaded

' Access PhotoView 360
Set swRayTraceRenderer = swApp.GetRayTraceRenderer(swPhotoView)
' Get and set rendering options
Set swRayTraceRenderOptions = swRayTraceRenderer.RayTraceRendererOptions
'Get current rendering values
Debug.Print "Current rendering values"
Debug.Print "  ImageHeight          = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ImageHeight
Debug.Print "  ImageWidth           = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ImageWidth
Debug.Print "  ImageFormat          = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ImageFormat
Debug.Print "  PreviewRenderQuality = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.PreviewRenderQuality
Debug.Print "  FinalRenderQuality   = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.FinalRenderQuality
Debug.Print "  BloomEnabled         = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.BloomEnabled
Debug.Print "  BloomThreshold       = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.BloomThreshold
Debug.Print "  BloomRadius          = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.BloomRadius
Debug.Print "  ContourEnabled       = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ContourEnabled
Debug.Print "  ShadedContour        = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ShadedContour
Debug.Print "  ContourLineThickness = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ContourLineThickness
Debug.Print "  ContourLineColor     = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ContourLineColor
Debug.Print " "
'Change rendering values
Debug.Print "New rendering values"
swRayTraceRenderOptions.ImageHeight = 405
Debug.Print "  ImageHeight          = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ImageHeight
swRayTraceRenderOptions.ImageWidth = 720
Debug.Print "  ImageWidth           = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ImageWidth
swRayTraceRenderOptions.ImageFormat = swImageFormat_PNG
Debug.Print "  ImageFormat          = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ImageFormat
swRayTraceRenderOptions.PreviewRenderQuality = swRenderQuality_Better
Debug.Print "  PreviewRenderQuality = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.PreviewRenderQuality
swRayTraceRenderOptions.FinalRenderQuality = swRenderQuality_Best
Debug.Print "  FinalRenderQuality   = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.FinalRenderQuality
swRayTraceRenderOptions.BloomEnabled = False
Debug.Print "  BloomEnabled         = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.BloomEnabled
swRayTraceRenderOptions.BloomThreshold = 0
Debug.Print "  BloomThreshold       = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.BloomThreshold
swRayTraceRenderOptions.BloomRadius = 0
Debug.Print "  BloomRadius          = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.BloomRadius
swRayTraceRenderOptions.ContourEnabled = False
Debug.Print "  ContourEnabled       = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ContourEnabled
swRayTraceRenderOptions.ShadedContour = False
Debug.Print "  ShadedContour        = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ShadedContour
swRayTraceRenderOptions.ContourLineThickness = 0
Debug.Print "  ContourLineThickness = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ContourLineThickness
swRayTraceRenderOptions.ContourLineColor = 255
Debug.Print "  ContourLineColor     = " & swRayTraceRenderOptions.ContourLineColor
' Display the preview window
status = swRayTraceRenderer.DisplayPreviewWindow
' Close render
status = swRayTraceRenderer.CloseRayTraceRender
' Invoke final render window
status = swRayTraceRenderer.InvokeFinalRender
' Abort final render window
status = swRayTraceRenderer.AbortFinalRender
' Render to Windows Bitmap format
status = swRayTraceRenderer.RenderToFile("C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\Renders Rob\" & i & z & ".png", 0, 0)
swRayTraceRenderOptions.FinalRenderQuality = swRenderQuality_Good
' Render to HDR format (format extension omitted)
status = swRayTraceRenderer.RenderToFile("C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\Renders Rob\" & i & z, 0, 0)
Set swRayTraceRenderOptions = Nothing
' Close render
status = swRayTraceRenderer.CloseRayTraceRender

swApp.QuitDoc i

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

With Solidworks tutorials : FloorShadows Property (ISwScene)

```
Option Explicit
     Dim Scene As SldWorks.SWScene
     Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
     Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
     Dim swConfig As SldWorks.Configuration
     Dim swPoint  As SldWorks.MathPoint
     Dim swVector As SldWorks.MathVector
     Dim point As Variant
     Dim vect As Variant

    Sub main()

        Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
         Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

        Set swConfig = swModel.GetActiveConfiguration
         Debug.Print "Configuration: " & swConfig.Name

        Set Scene = swConfig.GetScene

        Dim P2SFilename As String
         Scene.GetP2SFileName P2SFilename
         Debug.Print "Scene file: " & P2SFilename

        Scene.GetFloorNormal swPoint, swVector
         point = swPoint.ArrayData
         Debug.Print "Scene floor normal point: " & point(0) & ", " & point(1) & ", " & point(2)
         vect = swVector.ArrayData
         Debug.Print "Scene floor normal vector: " & vect(0) & ", " & vect(1) & ", " & vect(2)

        Dim value As Boolean
        Scene.FloorShadows = False '<- Here !
        value = Scene.FloorShadows 'debug

        Scene.BackgroundType = swSceneBackgroundType_e.swBackgroundType_UseEnvironment
         Debug.Print "Type of scene background as defined in swSceneBackgroundType_e: " & Scene.BackgroundType
         Debug.Print "Scene background environment image file: " & Scene.BackgroundEnvImage
         Debug.Print "Scene background image file: " & Scene.BackgroundImage
         Debug.Print "Scene environment rotation: " & Scene.EnvironmentRotation
         Scene.FitToSWWindow = True
         Debug.Print "Stretch to fit in SOLIDWORKS window? " & Scene.FitToSWWindow
         Debug.Print "Scale the scene floor uniformly? " & Scene.FixedAspectRatio
         Debug.Print "Flip the scene floor direction? " & Scene.FloorDirection
         Debug.Print "Automatically resize the scene floor based on the model bounding box? " & Scene.FloorAutoSize
         Debug.Print "Distance between scene floor and model: " & Scene.FloorOffset
         Debug.Print "Flip the scene floor offset direction? " & Scene.FloorOffsetDirection
         Scene.FloorReflections = True
         Debug.Print "Show model reflections on the scene floor? " & Scene.FloorReflections
         Debug.Print "Scene floor rotation: " & Scene.FloorRotation
         Debug.Print "Show model shadows on the scene floor? " & Scene.FloorShadows
         Debug.Print "Keep the scene background when changing the scene? " & Scene.KeepBackground
         Scene.FlattenFloor = True
         Debug.Print "Flatten the scene floor of the spherical environment? " & Scene.FlattenFloor
         Debug.Print "Horizon height: " & Scene.HorizonHeight
         Debug.Print "Environment size: " & Scene.EnvironmentSize

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have been searching for a sollution for a long time, you're the first one who seems to know how. I Tried to squees it into the rest of my code but now I'm getting errors which i can't solve :( I'll add my current code to my question, perhaps someone can have a look at it

Comment: oeps... juist found the first bug render tools was turned off

Comment: Got it running, but unfortiunately it still displays the shadow's in the png. file.